# Regex expression for "hotkey string"

Tags: javascript, regex

We need to find expression for search **"hotkey"** in string with **Javascript**.
That option, which is almost finds everything except sequences: `Ctrl + M, K, o, i`. As he finds `...` that absolutely we do not need :)

**EDIT:**

```
(?=((ctrl|alt|shift|,|\.|\/)+?\s*[+\-/]\s*(((numpad\s*[\w/\*\-\+\.]+)|(ctrl|alt|shift|,|\.|\/|[a-z]+)+?,?)\s*(?=((([a-z],)\s*[a-z])\s*,?\s*)?)\1(?=([a-z])?)\1)))\1
```

test multistring variant, **case insensitive**

```
<p>Ctrl + Insert, K</p>
<ul>Ctrl +,</ul>'
list Ctrl + , of end
colomn Ctrl + .</>'
<q>Ctrl + M</q>'
<a>Ctrl + M, K, o, i</a>
row Ctrl + M, , + P. While...
<rom>Ctrl + M, K, p</rom>'
<tag>Ctrl + M, Shift + O</tag>'
press Ctrl + M, Shift + O, , + P! Thanks.
Stop. Ctrl + M, Shift + O, / + P</end>
<anytag>Ctrl + Numpad +/-</anytag>'
```

Where am I wrong?

*Sorry, I can not insert preview due to insufficient reputation

Comment: Whatever this regex should match, probably not a range between `+` and `/` (`[+-/]`)...

Comment: @bobblebubble, I do not understand what you mean by that? I fixed there a sign of shielding error `-`. `[+-/]` -> `[+\-/]`

Comment: @bobblebubble that regex should be interpreted as just the three characters, although I've not tried that in all browsers. It's not _mandatory_ to do so but it also less likely for that to be interpreted as a range.

Comment: @vlaz My comment was before q was edited. Wenceslaus, what I meant was same that Sunny Pun answered and explained in detail.

Comment: @bobblebubble mine was also referencing the same thing. `[+-/]` should resolve to the same as `[+\-/]`. Again, it's not _mandatory_, for the dash loses it's special meaning only if it's in the beginning/end, however, at the same time there is no "range between `+` and `/`" and such a regex is meaningless, thus all sensible browsers should treat the dash as a simply a dash. Again, haven't tested it everywhere.

Comment: @vlaz I only tested it in [JS mode in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BtwrSX/1) which indicates *a single character in the range between + (ASCII 43) and / (ASCII 47)* as also Sunny described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the group `(ctrl|alt|shift|,|\.|\/)+?` it captures a `.`
In the character class you haven't escaped the `-`, so `[+-/]` indeed acts as "characters between ascii value of `+`(43) and `/`(47), which namely are `+,-./`.
In the last group before the `|`, you also allowed it to capture a third `.`. 
Thus `...` can be captured, you may avoid this by escaping the `-` with `[+\-/]`.

Here is a version that I guess may work for you:

```
(ctrl|shift|alt)\s*\+\s*([a-z+\-.,/]|Numpad\s*[0-9+\-/]+|insert)(\s*(,|\+)\s*((ctrl|shift|alt)\s*\+\s*)*([a-z+\-.,/]|Numpad\s*[0-9+\-/]+|insert))*(?=\W)
```

I am using https://regex101.com/ to see matches in realtime.

1. I start with thinking that it should capture units (`a-z,.+-/`) so I now have `[a-z+\-.,/]` (to avoid confusion I didn't use `[+-/]` directly.
2. And then, we shouldn't capture `C`,`t`,`r`,`l` or any word as separated matches.  So I added a *positive lookbehind*: `[a-z+\-.,/](?=\W)`
3. It should start with a modifier key (Ctrl, Alt, Shift) as a sequence - otherwise it may capture normal English words like `I`: `(ctrl|shift|alt)\s*\+\s*[a-z+\-.,/](?=\W)`
4. Suddenly, oh `Numpad` with `0-9+-/` should be also units, let's make the character class in step 1 a group, for capturing units: `(ctrl|shift|alt)\s*\+\s*([a-z+\-.,/]|Numpad\s*[0-9+\-/]+)(?=\W)`
5. And I also add `Insert` as one of the capturable units: `(ctrl|shift|alt)\s*\+\s*([a-z+\-.,/]|Numpad\s*[0-9+\-/]+|insert)(?=\W)`
6. Finally, let's add the repeating group which captures `,(units)` occurring after the first captured Hotkeys (Modifier + unit): `(ctrl|shift|alt)\s*\+\s*([a-z+\-.,/]|Numpad\s*[0-9+\-/]+|insert)()*(?=\W)`.  Yup, adding a blank `()*` to ensure the regex is still balanced and working for old matches.
7. We put group 2 into the empty bracket so it works as we thought: `, with units`: `(ctrl|shift|alt)\s*\+\s*([a-z+\-.,/]|Numpad\s*[0-9+\-/]+|insert)(\s*,\s*([a-z+\-.,/]|Numpad\s*[0-9+\-/]+|insert))*(?=\W)`
8. The only one we cannot capture is `, + P` and `/ + P`, because we haven't captured `unit + unit` groups! And we may have it repeated a number of times... The easiest and laziest way - making the `+` also as a separator (same level as `,`): `(ctrl|shift|alt)\s*\+\s*([a-z+\-.,/]|Numpad\s*[0-9+\-/]+|insert)(\s*(,|\+)\s*([a-z+\-.,/]|Numpad\s*[0-9+\-/]+|insert))*(?=\W)`
9. Understanding the above, we want `Ctrl + M, Shift + O, / + P` to be captured - that means, we should also add optional modifiers in front of the units: `(ctrl|shift|alt)\s*\+\s*([a-z+\-.,/]|Numpad\s*[0-9+\-/]+|insert)(\s*(,|\+)\s*((ctrl|shift|alt)\s*\+\s*)*([a-z+\-.,/]|Numpad\s*[0-9+\-/]+|insert))*(?=\W)`

Comment: Thanks! I was inattentive. I fixed it, but sequences is still not found `Ctrl + M, K, o, i`

Comment: Do you want to accept infinitely long sequences? Instead of using `|`, you may consider a pattern like `(....)(\s*,\s*\1)*` so you have to only work on the first big group which checks all sequences.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm new to regular expressions, you do not complicate write your option here?)

Comment: Sorry I don't have access to a computer at the moment. You may try pasting your Regex to http://www.regexplained.co.uk and see if the sequence can be captured by any path in the graph generated.

Comment: @Wenceslaus Answer edited. Please take a look and if that answers your question please accept an answer ;) I can provide more explanations if the answer is not clear enough.

Comment: Oh yeah! This is a fantastic work!! Many thanks for the explanation, it is now all clear! :)